# Google Script email confirmation with url hyperlink

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a script to send an email to individuals when a form is submitted and in the email I have a link/url to the page. I want to be able to hyperlink the url address to a word or phrase like "Click Here". How can I do this in Google Script?

[image: Screenshot of my script]

Answer (score 2):

Google Apps Mail allows you to set an `htmlBody`, which will be rendered as HTML instead of plain text.

There you can use a standard HTML `<a>` tag to create a link:

```
<a href="http://mypage.com">Click me!</a>
```

Have a look at [the Google Apps Mail docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app) for more info.